# How to handle dynamic JSON with Retrofit 2?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I have 2 types of reponse for one url. First is List of objects and second is error response object.

First:

```
[
    {
       id: 1,
       title: "title1",
       description: "",
       position: 1000
    },

    {
       id: 2,
       title: "title3",
       description: "",
       position: 1000
    },

    {
       id: 3,
       title: "title3",
       description: "",
       position: 1000
    }
 ]
```

Second:

```
{
   "status":"error",
   "error":"no token"
}
```

Any ideas how to handle it with Retrofit 2? When server returns error response I have error: "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $"

Category.class

```
public class Category{

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Id id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("position")
    @Expose
    private Integer position;


    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The id
     */
    public Id getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     * The id
     */
    public void setId(Id id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The title
     */
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param title
     * The title
     */
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The description
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param description
     * The description
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The position
     */
    public Integer getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param position
     * The position
     */
    public void setPosition(Integer position) {
        this.position = position;
    }



}
```

Request to the server:

```
 public void loadCategories(final boolean pullToRefresh) {

        Call<List<Category>> categoriesCall = mRequestHandler.getCategories(Keys.CATEGORY_CATALOGS);

        categoriesCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Category>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Category>> call, Response<List<Category>> response) {

                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    getView().setData(response.body());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Category>> call, Throwable t) {

                getView().showError(null, pullToRefresh);
                Log.e("Error:", t.getMessage());

            }

        });


    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Use a wrapper response object where your array will bei in and also the error properties. Either one will be null, check for it to see what kind of reaponse you got. Of the top of my head I dont know if its possible to use array and object at the same time as response

Comment: Fix your server. The response can't be an array or an object. Otherwise, you'll have to do without Retrofit and manually parse your objects and catch that exception

Comment: I am looking for a solution to this question

Answer (score 0):

what I can see is that your server is sending error on HTTP_STATUS 200.
This is why retrofit is considering it as a response and not an error.
making this change to server side will result in 
public void onFailure(Call> call, Throwable t) invocation.